# Drupal Login page

Tags: drupal-6

I am new to drupal.and I get stuck in some of the tasks.
Currently i want to edit/create my landing page in drupal which should be different than the themes i am using now.
if anyone knows how to integrate new page in drupal please let me know

Thanks

Shrik

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad. Lots of different ways to accomplish "new page" in drupal including just making a "page" using the page module, creating a new menu path in a custom module, and those are just the 2 most obvious. Can you give more details on what you are trying to accomplish with this "new page"